# Page Block section is disturbing the table structure

Tags: visualforce, table, pageblocksection, pageblock

I have a Visualforce page, which is showing table.

```
<apex:page controller="TestControllerForIssue">
    <style type="text/css">
        .myClass { width: 50px; }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Edition</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:inputText styleClass="myClass" value="{!productQuantity}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!model}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I need to add pageBlockSection.

Added like this:

```
<apex:page controller="TestControllerForIssue">
    <style type="text/css">
        .myClass { width: 50px; }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="productData">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Edition</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:inputText styleClass="myClass" value="{!productQuantity}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!model}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

After adding the section, the table structure is changed in page.

It is now looking like this:

[image]

How should I use the pageBlock section with table so the structure of the table is not changed?

Comment: Varun, You need to add the structure like `PageBlock -> PageBlockSection -> PageBlockSection -> table`  , or you can use PageBlockTable structure.

Comment: @Rahul Added page block section as above hierarchy. But the page is still not in structure

Comment: I forgot to mention PageBlockSectionItem please add the structure like `PageBlock -> PageBlockSection -> PageBlockSection -> PageBlockSectionItem -> table` and keep column=1 on PageBlockSection  like `<apex:PageBlockSection  columns="1">`

Comment: Getting issue **<apex:pageBlockSectionItem> may have no more than 2 child components**

Comment: Your demo code doesn't seem to match what I'd expect to happen it you had that kind of output on the screen. Please make sure the code matches the screenshot's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `PageBlockSection` with `HTML` table, you will have to include `PageBlockSectionItem` and have an `outputPanel` inside `PageBlockSectionItem`. And `columns` attribute of `PageBlockSection` should be set to `1`.

The reason `outputPanel` is included inside `PageBlockSectionItem` is because, you cannot directly have `html` table as its child component, as it won't allow more than 2 child components. Hence, add an `outputPanel` as child component, which will be the only child component of `PageBlockSectionItem` and set the `columns` attribute of `PageBlockSection` to `1`.

Below visualforce page should work

```
<apex:page controller="TestControllerForIssue">
    <style type="text/css">
        .myClass { width: 50px; }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="productData" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
                                <th style="text-align: center">Edition</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><apex:inputText styleClass="myClass" value="{!productQuantity}"/></td>
                                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!model}"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```